# How can I make my code respond to user input

Tags: python, input

I want to create a help command in my game.

- Whenever the user gives an input of help:

  - something helpful should print
  - then it should take another input

```
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 7
first_input = input("type a command ")
if first_input == 'help':
#here when first input = help it print something after it should take 
#another input if this input again equal to help print something and so 
#on print('something')
if first_input == start:
    while guess_count < guess_limit
#some code and if there is/are a input/s in this code and it/they are 
#equal to help it should print something
```

Comment: Updated syntax of question and added `input` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 7
while True: # do infinite loop
    first_input = input("type a command ")
    if first_input == 'help':
        print("something")
    elif first_input == start:
        while guess_count < guess_limit:
            # do something
            pass
```